# Can wait_for_message check for multiple contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I am waiting for a message like:

```
msg = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content = '.hit')
```

What I want to do though is to wait for a message, and proceed with 2 different kinds of content, for example:

```
msg = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author, content = '.hit' or '.pass')
```

While this does not throw any errors, it does not work. I checked with:

```
if msg.content == (".hit"):

    print("He hits.")

elif msg.content == (".pass"):

    print("He passes.")

else:

   print("It did not work.")
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can just do this:

```
msg = (await bot.wait_for("message")).content
```

```py
    if msg == ".hit":
        print("He hits!")
    elif msg == ".pass":
        print("He passes!")
    else:
        print("He doesn't do anything")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
content = '.hit' or '.pass'
```

will not do what you think it will, it (if you check in idle) will just return `'.hit'` for what you want to do, simply don't include the content keyword argument and check the content yourself like so

```
msg = await bot.wait_for_message(author=message.author)
if msg:
    if msg.content == '.hit':
        print('He hits')
    elif msg.content == '.pass':
        print('He passes')
    else:
        print('He didn\'t give a valid option')
```

The reason why I put an `if msg` branch first is that if you have a timeout set, the bot will return `None` in place of a `discord.Message`